# How to retrieve values from mysql database from 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, database, select

users table:

```
userID | name
1      | John
2      | Mary
3      | Jack
```

items table(the users will select and store into mysql

```
itemID | name   | item 
1      | Mary   | pants, jeans
1      | John   | jacket, shirt
1      | Jack   | jacket, shirt
```

description table (retrieve the description based on what user select the items)

```
descID | item          | descOne | descTwo
1      | jacket, shirt | Nice!   | Great   
1      | pants, jeans  | good    | Nice    
1      | dress, jeans  | Nice!   | Great
```

If I want to retrieve values of Mary, what should my select sql statement be?

Currently I have this ->

```
SELECT 
    d.item, 
    d.descOne, 
    d.descTwo, 
    i.name , d.item
FROM description d 
INNER JOIN items i 
WHERE d.item = i.item ON;
```

Comment: it would be good if you define foreign keys instead of item and user names as foreign keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.name,
    d.descOne, 
    d.descTwo, 
    d.item
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN items as i ON i.name = u.name
LEFT JOIN description as d ON d.item = i.item
WHERE u.name = 'Mary'
```

Comment: But I can't hard code 'Mary' there. Have to retrieve base on user who logged in example like fb.

Comment: i know you can't hardcode but you can provide variable holding logged in user name in you can pass this query to run